# Hotkey for insert equation to word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, hotkeys, microsoft-office-2010, equations

It's not so convenient to go to insert --> equation --> insert new equation everytime you want to create a new one. I guess there must be some hotkey to insert an inline equation at the current cursor position? However, Microsoft Office Help doesn't help (as usual). I tried google it but there aren't any solution work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's "Alt+=", but it only works in docx files and you should have VB-component installed to enable macros.

Comment: +1. This should definitely be the accepted answer. It is also very easy to find out hotkeys yourself. Simply go to to the options dialog, select 'Advanced', and make sure that the checkbox named 'Show hotkeys in tooltips' is checked. Then you simply have to hover your cursor above a button to see the associated hotkey.

Comment: Yes good point. I can only add that this option is under Advanced->Display->"Show shortcut keys in ScreenTips" on my installation of Word 2010.

Comment: Yes, since my Word 2010 is in Swedish, I have to translate freely into English... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create a macros and assign to key any you like (See last button on View tab). It's not difficult - start record and click equation button. Then stop record.

Comment: :) That just works! Thx you ^^

Comment: Yes, it might work, but it isn't good.